# OpenCV IplImage to CGImageRef

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, opencv, cgimageref

Im using OpenCV for iOS in a OS X project, and everything has set up fine so far. Im looking to read in frames from a video file, but I need them to be of type `CGImageRef`, not the `IplImage` like they are when I read them.

My question is simple: How do I convert from an `IplImage` to a `CGImageRef`?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/sonsongithub/OpenCV-Help-Library.

The first functions that were built in are converters for `IplImage` and `CGImageRef`